# Set Max value in Where condition in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to get **role_id** from a preference table with some conditions, including it should not belong to the maximum **level** column. Here is the code,

```
$maxLevel = ApprovalPreference::where('company_id', $this->company_id)
    ->max('level'); // Can this line be avoided???
$role = ApprovalPreference::where('company_id', $this->company_id)
    ->where('level', '>', $this->approval_level)
    ->where('level', '<', $maxLevel)
    ->orderBy('level', 'asc')
    ->pluck('role_id')
    ->first();
```

The above code works, but is there a way to incorporate the line which fetches the maximum value to the main query?
I tried the raw query but it did not work,

```
->where('level', '<', DB::raw('select MAX(level) from approval_preferences')
```

The above code did not work, it threw some errors.

EDIT

The above code worked when I wrapped the select statement in another set of paranthesis.

```
->where('level', '<', DB::raw('(select MAX(level) from approval_preferences)')
```

END

Eventually I used whereRaw method,

```
->whereRaw("level > (SELECT MAX(level) from approval_preferences where company_id = {$this->company_id})")
```

*keeping the question undeleted considering the others who tried to help me out*

Comment: Use: ->whereRaw('level < (select MAX(level) from approval_preferences)')

Comment: I would recommend setting up a trait with the condition in it then call the trait. $this->model->level->where('company_id', $id);

Comment: @YasinPatel It shows the same error as the DB:raw,  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select MAX(level) from approval_preferences order by `level` desc' at line 1 (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `role_id` from `approval_preferences` where ... `level` < 2 and `level` > select MAX(level) from approval_preferences order by `level` desc)

Comment: @levi thanks but I think I will need to look deep into how trait can solve this issue

Comment: @SabinChacko Laravel Traits will help you significantly! It will help you a lot especially if youre relationships are defined accordingly within your migration/models. I just refactored a large application and simplified a ton of my queries by using traits and methods that applied to multiple models or even a single.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution for you is to use whereRaw

```php
$role = ApprovalPreference::where('company_id', $this->company_id)
    ->where('level', '>', $this->approval_level)
    ->whereRaw("level < (SELECT MAX(level) from table_approval_preference WHERE company_id = $this->company_id"))
    ->orderBy('level', 'asc')
    ->pluck('role_id')
    ->first();
```

Comment: That is not a correct solution, as the author is looking for the COMPANY ID's MAX LEVEL, not the table max level

Comment: @matiaslauriti I added the condition to get the necessary column. But I followed this method eventually.

Comment: Sorry @matiaslauriti i missing: WHERE company_id = $this->company_id in whereRaw

Answer (score 4):

Here I have used a subquery to filter data, try this:

```
$role = ApprovalPreference::where('company_id', $this->company_id)
    ->where('level', '>', $this->approval_level)
    ->where('level', '<', function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('MAX(level)'))
            ->from('approval_preferences')
            ->where('company_id', $this->company_id);
    })
    ->orderBy('level')
    ->pluck('role_id')
    ->first();
```

Comment: I chose the whereRaw method instead. but +1 for the help.